# How to store a word list for that also allows for easy editing?

Tags: android

What is the best way to store a word list on android that can easily be edited on something like excel. I tried a xml but when I say the xml in excel and then open it in a text editor the save doesnt take. Im new to android and could use some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Please further explain your problem and attach relevant code

Comment: All I want to know is what the best way to go from excel sheet that has a list/array of words to a xml file or file that can be used by android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

export it into a .csv file (comma separated)

for example

```
for(int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++){
     outputFile.write(yourList.get(i) + ",");
}
```

and make sure the extension of the output file is .csv